# Image in widget magento 2.1

Tags: image, widget

I follow this for add an image uploader in widget https://gist.github.com/cedricblondeau/6174911fb4bba6cb4943
But i get an js error "Uncaught ReferenceError: MediabrowserUtility is not defined"
Any body have experience on this please help me